# Unable to use String variable outside if statement

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have implemented timer like this (Mentioned in code). I changed its string format so that it takes `hours:minutes:seconds` and for me, to use a switch, I have to add an `if(){}` conditional statement.

So I did and I had to declare the string inside the `if(){}` cause i couldnt do it outside `if(){}`. But now I want to use that string information for an intent to open a new activity and assign the string value to a **TextView**.

The problem is I can't use the string outside of the `if(){}` and at first I used the ***hms*** string with a **TextView** called ***myText***.

The thing is that the myText TextView worked perfectly on the first activity but when sending the information using **Inetnt** to another **Textview** in the other activity it showed no change on the **TextView**.

Heres is the code:

```
 if (mySwitch.isChecked()) {
                        int getvaluehour = numPickerHour.getValue();
                        int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();

                        getvaluehour = getvaluehour * 3600000;
                        getvalueminute = getvalueminute * 60000;
                        long hoursandMinstomils = getvalueminute + getvaluehour;

                        new CountDownTimer(hoursandMinstomils, 1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                                long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                                //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
                                 String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                                myText.setText(hms);

                            }

                            public void onFinish() {

                                myText.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text
                            }
                        }.start();
```

and heres how i used the **Intent** Activity1:

```
Intent toST = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTime.class);

                        String textMessage = myText.getText().toString() ;
                        toST.putExtra("wargra", textMessage);

                        startActivity(toST);
```

and heres how I received it in activity2:

```
Bundle receiver = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(receiver == null){
            return;
        }

        String textMessage = reciver.getString("wargra");
        myText2.setText(textMessage);
```

How can I send hms value to myText2?

Here is the complete activity1 code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button silentButton;
    AudioManager myAudioManager;
    NumberPicker numPickerHour;
    NumberPicker numPickerMin;
    Switch mySwitch;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Text,Audio,Button,Time

        myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        silentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);

        //Number Picker
        numPickerHour = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPickerHour);
        numPickerMin = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMinute);
        mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Toggle);

        //Hour
        numPickerHour.setMaxValue(24);
        numPickerHour.setMinValue(0);
        numPickerHour.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        //Min
        numPickerMin.setMaxValue(60);
        numPickerMin.setMinValue(0);
        numPickerMin.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);



        silentButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        final TextView myText;
                        myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);



                        if (mySwitch.isChecked()) {
                            int getvaluehour = numPickerHour.getValue();
                            int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();

                            getvaluehour = getvaluehour * 3600000;
                            getvalueminute = getvalueminute * 60000;
                            long hoursandMinstomils = getvalueminute + getvaluehour;

                            new CountDownTimer(hoursandMinstomils, 1000) {

                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                                    long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                                    //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
                                     String hms = String.format("Viberation end in: " + "%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                                    myText.setText(hms);


                                    //set text

                                    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                                    myText.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text
                                }
                            }.start();

                        } else {
                            int getvaluehour = numPickerHour.getValue();
                            int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();

                            getvaluehour = getvaluehour * 3600000;
                            getvalueminute = getvalueminute * 60000;
                            long hoursandMinstomils = getvalueminute + getvaluehour;

                            new CountDownTimer(hoursandMinstomils, 1000) {

                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                                    long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                                    //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
                                    String hms = String.format("Silent ends in (" + "%02d:%02d:%02d" + ")", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                                    myText.setText(hms);//set text

                                    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                                    myText.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }


                        Intent toST = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTime.class);

                        String textMessage = myText.getText().toString() ;
                        toST.putExtra("wargra", textMessage);

                        startActivity(toST);

                    }
                }
        );


                        }
                    }
```

Comment: can you add your whole activity.1 code? it's hard to say when you are getting the value from your textView for the intent without the complete code.

Comment: It would be wonderful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SudipPodder i just edited it and in the first one i didnt include every code but now its the complete activity one the reason i didnt include all was so make it more simple to find a solution and i knew the code i did not include had nothing to do with my problem

Comment: @kardio did you debug your code ?, put a break point  near your intent code and near your bundle receive code, see what value is being received.

Comment: How do i put a break point??

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextView myText;
myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
```

Change these two lines. Declare myText globally (as you have already done with silentButton, myAudioManager, numPickerHour, numPickerMin, mySwitch).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Following your other code
    ....

    TextView myText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Following your other code
        ....

        myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);

        //Rest of your code
        ....

    }
}
```

Hope your problem will be gone.

Comment: No i tried it, and it did not work. The problem isn't with that its that i cant show the time on the TextView in the second activity!

Comment: Your second activity is supposed to show "TIME'S UP!!" is the myText2 textView with the current code of yours. What is it showing right now?

Answer (score 0):

**There could be two reasons and solutions:**

**case 1:** If you are using your `if` inside a Thread then you should update the `TextView` on `UIThread` i.e `MainThread`.

Like this:

```
if (mySwitch.isChecked()) {
                    int getvaluehour = numPickerHour.getValue();
                    int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();

                    getvaluehour = getvaluehour * 3600000;
                    getvalueminute = getvalueminute * 60000;
                    long hoursandMinstomils = getvalueminute + getvaluehour;

                    new CountDownTimer(hoursandMinstomils, 1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                            long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                            //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
                             String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable()
                                 {
                                 @Override
                                 public void run()
                                    {
                                    myText.setText(hms);
                                    }
                                 }).start();

                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable()
                                 {
                                 @Override
                                 public void run()
                                    {
                                    myText.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text
                                    }
                                 }).start();

                        }
                    }.start();
```

You should always update any UI element on MainThread only by using the runOnUIThread() method. May be this was the cause of your problem.

**case 2:** Solution given by Sudip Podder.

**case 3** : Answer to your query :
In java you can not just use a variable outside of its scope. All you can do the thing is to put the value to class variable like this :
Just declare a class variable and put value in it and then use the class variable for the values.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
....
....
String time;
....
....
}
....
....
....
if (mySwitch.isChecked()) {
                int getvaluehour = numPickerHour.getValue();
                int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();

                getvaluehour = getvaluehour * 3600000;
                getvalueminute = getvalueminute * 60000;
                long hoursandMinstomils = getvalueminute + getvaluehour;

                new CountDownTimer(hoursandMinstomils, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                        //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
                         String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                        MainActivity.this.time=hms;
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable()
                             {
                             @Override
                             public void run()
                                {
                                myText.setText(MainActivity.this.time);
                                }
                             }).start();

                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable()
                             {
                             @Override
                             public void run()
                                {
                                myText.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text
                                }
                             }).start();
```

Now you can use the value of hms variable by the class variable `time`. And yes don't forget to declare myText as class variable.

Comment: i just need a way to access the String hms outside the IF is that possible?